# How to scale out on every page in single page application

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I have been working on a single page application..since the content is very large and mobile version is not yet ready.. 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
I removed scaling for website by removing the meta tags.. so i am getting a desktop view in Mobile devices . But when the user zooms into by tapping an area and then he navigates to a new page..he still remains on same zoom level. I want to scale out on every page he navigates...how to achieve this.

Comment: a single page app does not navigate or do page refreshes.  right?

Comment: Yes. It wont @ron

Comment: Even during reload it stays the same state @Ron Royston

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This just might be a duplicate of either this [change-page-zoom-in-mobile-safari-via-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574189/is-is-possible-to-change-page-zoom-in-mobile-safari-via-javascript), or this [force-mobile-browser-zoom-out-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639296/force-mobile-browser-zoom-out-with-javascript) ... let me know if, and I close it as such